# Pass data selected values ​when the keys of a dictionary match

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add some values ​​from one dictionary to another, but it is giving me an error at the moment of not finding the key.

Note: I do not make this change from the database since the queries come from different sources, so I have to do this exercise.

These are my dictionaries:

**`apro`**

```
{'220005124956': ('220005124956', '0460', '655', 'N', 1008, '68547', 'N'), '220004340180': ('220004340180', '0110', '621', 'N', 1008, '13001',  'N'), '220005432952': ('220005432952', '0511', '0', 'S', 1008, '66170', 'S')}
```

**`qval`**

```
{'220005124956': ('220005124956', 57, 57, 'Viable', '22/03/19', '30/01/77', 'SOLICITANTE', 4), '220001563164': ('220001563164',  0, 103, 'Viable', '28/06/19', '14/08/53','DEUDOR SOLIDARIO', 1), '220002018427': ('220002018427',  31, 134, 'Viable', '23/05/19', '07/04/61', 'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220002389190': ('220002389190',  0, 52, 'Viable', '27/03/19', '26/04/63', 'SOLICITANTE', 2), '220005432952': ('220005432952', 23, 23, 'Viable', '06/06/19', '03/11/79',  'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220002392626': ('220002392626', 15, 15, 'Viable', '23/02/21', '23/09/67', 'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220003040975': ('220003040975', 23, 153, 'Viable', '05/03/21', '06/01/58', 6, 'SOLICITANTE', 4), '220004790251': ('220004790251', 20, 20, 'Viable', '09/07/19', '01/01/54', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003721210': ('220003721210', 20, 21, 'Viable', '05/12/19', '15/11/84','SOLICITANTE',  3), '220003799655': ('220003799655', 0, 0, 'Viable', '25/06/21', '20/03/72', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003800434': ('220003800434', 21, 162, 'Viable', '16/11/21', '13/07/66', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003851821': ('220003851821', 24, 22, 'Viable', '09/09/19', '18/10/81', 'SOLICITANTE', 2), '220003851944': ('220003851944', 8, 12, 'Viable', '27/09/19', '22/12/64','SOLICITANTE', 3), '220004430315': ('220004430315', 18, 39, 'Viable', '07/10/21', '14/02/53', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220004504137': ('220004504137', 40, 54, 'Viable', '19/03/19', '08/03/86','SOLICITANTE', 1), '220004510839': ('220004510839',  0, 98, 'Viable', '12/10/19', '10/02/72','SOLICITANTE', 3), '220004511887': ('220004511887', '23, 137, 'Viable', '14/01/20', '05/05/59', 'SOLICITANTE', 1)}
```

This is the error that generates me.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\adherencia.py", line 172, in <module>
    Base_adherencia()
  File "\adherencia.py", line 151, in adherencia
    res[key].append(apro + '', '', '', '')
KeyError: '220004340180'
```

This is my code:

```
def UnirDic():
    apro = {}
    for row in pcorte: ##pcorte is the result of a sql query
        apro[row[0]] = row
      
    val = Validaciones() ##Validaciones is the result of a sql query
    qval = {}
    for row in val:
        qval[row[0]]=row
    
    res = {}   

    for key, apro_row in apro.items():        
        qval_row = qval[key] if key in qval else res[key].append(apro + [qval_row[1], qval_row[2], qval_row[4], qval_row[7]])
        res[key].append(apro + '', '', '', '')
        
    for key, apro_row in res.items():
        print(key,apro_row)
```

Comment: The error message is saying you're trying to append something to a list value that does not exist at `res[key]`. It's not clear why you would think there should be. Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: `dic 2` is not valid to start with. I typed it into my Python interpreter and got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Answer (score 0):

`res[key].append(x)` works like this:

1. Get the value corresponding to `key` from dictionary `res`
2. Call the `.append` method on the result of (1)

Now, `res` starts off as an empty dictionary with no keys.  So step 1 is going to fail because `key` isn't present.

One solution is to replace the problematic line with:

```
res.setdefault(key, []).append((apro + '', '', '', ''))
```

Note, as well as the problem with `key`, you had a missing set of parentheses around the argument of `append`.

Also, have a look at the previous line.  In the `else` case you're trying to assign the result of `append` to `qval_row`, which probably won't do what you intend, because `append` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, I can only guess that you want to merge one dictionary to another by its keys, where both dicts have tuple data types. If that's true, it's easily achieved using this code:

```py
d1 = {'220005124956': ('220005124956', '0460', '655', 'N', 1008, '68547', 'N'), '220004340180': ('220004340180', '0110', '621', 'N', 1008, '13001',  'N'), '220005432952': ('220005432952', '0511', '0', 'S', 1008, '66170', 'S')}
d2 = {'220005124956': ('220005124956', 57, 57, 'Viable', '22/03/19', '30/01/77', 'SOLICITANTE', 4), '220001563164': ('220001563164',  0, 103, 'Viable', '28/06/19', '14/08/53','DEUDOR SOLIDARIO', 1), '220002018427': ('220002018427',  31, 134, 'Viable', '23/05/19', '07/04/61', 'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220002389190': ('220002389190',  0, 52, 'Viable', '27/03/19', '26/04/63', 'SOLICITANTE', 2), '220005432952': ('220005432952', 23, 23, 'Viable', '06/06/19', '03/11/79',  'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220002392626': ('220002392626', 15, 15, 'Viable', '23/02/21', '23/09/67', 'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220003040975': ('220003040975', 23, 153, 'Viable', '05/03/21', '06/01/58', 6, 'SOLICITANTE', 4), '220004790251': ('220004790251', 20, 20, 'Viable', '09/07/19', '01/01/54', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003721210': ('220003721210', 20, 21, 'Viable', '05/12/19', '15/11/84','SOLICITANTE',  3), '220003799655': ('220003799655', 0, 0, 'Viable', '25/06/21', '20/03/72', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003800434': ('220003800434', 21, 162, 'Viable', '16/11/21', '13/07/66', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003851821': ('220003851821', 24, 22, 'Viable', '09/09/19', '18/10/81', 'SOLICITANTE', 2), '220003851944': ('220003851944', 8, 12, 'Viable', '27/09/19', '22/12/64','SOLICITANTE', 3), '220004430315': ('220004430315', 18, 39, 'Viable', '07/10/21', '14/02/53', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220004504137': ('220004504137', 40, 54, 'Viable', '19/03/19', '08/03/86','SOLICITANTE', 1), '220004510839': ('220004510839',  0, 98, 'Viable', '12/10/19', '10/02/72','SOLICITANTE', 3), '220004511887': ('220004511887', '23', 137, 'Viable', '14/01/20', '05/05/59', 'SOLICITANTE', 1)}

# Assuming you want to add values from d1 to values from d2 and allow duplicates
for key in d1:
  if key in d2:
    d2[key] = tuple(list(d1[key]) + list(d2[key]))
```

##### Edit

IIUC, you want to add only specific values (determined by list of indices) from one dict to another for the same key. Then you can do something like this:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

d1 = {'220005124956': ('220005124956', '0460', '655', 'N', 1008, '68547', 'N'), '220004340180': ('220004340180', '0110', '621', 'N', 1008, '13001',  'N'), '220005432952': ('220005432952', '0511', '0', 'S', 1008, '66170', 'S')}
d2 = {'220005124956': ('220005124956', 57, 57, 'Viable', '22/03/19', '30/01/77', 'SOLICITANTE', 4), '220001563164': ('220001563164',  0, 103, 'Viable', '28/06/19', '14/08/53','DEUDOR SOLIDARIO', 1), '220002018427': ('220002018427',  31, 134, 'Viable', '23/05/19', '07/04/61', 'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220002389190': ('220002389190',  0, 52, 'Viable', '27/03/19', '26/04/63', 'SOLICITANTE', 2), '220005432952': ('220005432952', 23, 23, 'Viable', '06/06/19', '03/11/79',  'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220002392626': ('220002392626', 15, 15, 'Viable', '23/02/21', '23/09/67', 'SOLICITANTE', 3), '220003040975': ('220003040975', 23, 153, 'Viable', '05/03/21', '06/01/58', 6, 'SOLICITANTE', 4), '220004790251': ('220004790251', 20, 20, 'Viable', '09/07/19', '01/01/54', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003721210': ('220003721210', 20, 21, 'Viable', '05/12/19', '15/11/84','SOLICITANTE',  3), '220003799655': ('220003799655', 0, 0, 'Viable', '25/06/21', '20/03/72', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003800434': ('220003800434', 21, 162, 'Viable', '16/11/21', '13/07/66', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220003851821': ('220003851821', 24, 22, 'Viable', '09/09/19', '18/10/81', 'SOLICITANTE', 2), '220003851944': ('220003851944', 8, 12, 'Viable', '27/09/19', '22/12/64','SOLICITANTE', 3), '220004430315': ('220004430315', 18, 39, 'Viable', '07/10/21', '14/02/53', 'SOLICITANTE', 1), '220004504137': ('220004504137', 40, 54, 'Viable', '19/03/19', '08/03/86','SOLICITANTE', 1), '220004510839': ('220004510839',  0, 98, 'Viable', '12/10/19', '10/02/72','SOLICITANTE', 3), '220004511887': ('220004511887', '23', 137, 'Viable', '14/01/20', '05/05/59', 'SOLICITANTE', 1)}
get_ind_positions = [1, 3]

# Assuming you want to add values from d1 to values from d2 and allow duplicates
for key in d1:
  if key in d2:
    d2[key] = tuple(list(d1[key]) + list(itemgetter(*get_ind_positions)(list(d2[key]))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have understood part of it, I am new to the language and part of this data structure, it effectively joins the dictionaries completely, but I only need to join some positions, I tried to indicate which ones but it gives me the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\adherencia.py", line 185, in <module>
    Base_adhesion()
  File "\adherencia.py", line 156, in Base_adherencia
    qval[key] = tuple(list(apro[key])+ list(qval[1], qval[2], qval[4], qval[7]))
KeyError: 1

Comment: @FerneyGuerrero, can you share the positions on which you want to merge the dicts? Do you have them stored in a list? Please provide more information

Comment: yes, in the statement they are apro and qval, for example, from the key 220005124956 of the qval dictionary, I only want to add position 3 of qval to apro ('Viable')

Comment: @FerneyGuerrero, so you want to add 'N' from qval (third position if you count 0) to apro for the corresponding key, understood. But how to you want to add it? what is the rule? Do you want to add it at the same position in apro, in this case at 'Viable'? And what do you mean by adding, so like ('Viable', 'N'), or like ('ViableN')?

Comment: as such it is to add elements when the key matches, for this example it would be to add the value of the position [1] and [3] of the dictionary (qval), leaving as a result all the values ​​of apro + qval(1,3).
Imagine doing it with get, like this
res[key] = tuple(list(apro[key]) + list(qval[key].get(1,3)))

but it gives me an error
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @FerneyGuerrero, sorry, I missed your comment. I edited my solution.

Answer (score 0):

you should try using [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict),

in your imports:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
```

in `UnirDic()`, initialize res like this:

```py
res = defaultdict(list)
```